# Find the minimum of average value

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, optimization

Let $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ be a non-decreasing function. What is the solution to the following problem $$\inf_{y\in[0,1]} \frac{1}{y}\int_0^yf(x)dx?$$

Since $f$ is non-decreasing, the average is minimized by sending $y\to 0$, in which case we get $f(0)$? Does this make sense?

Comment: Now try combinations of non-increasing and sup.

Comment: I don't see why you can conclude that fast that the minimum is obtained when $y\to 0$. $f$ is non decreasing, but $y\mapsto \frac1y\int_0^yf$ may not _a priori_ be itself non decreasing. You have to show that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's correct except that we get $\lim\limits_{x \to 0+} f(x)$ - $f$ doesn't need to be continuous (but one-sided limit exists, as $f$ is non-decreasing).